# React Big Calendar Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

**First error:**

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.

**Second error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'momentLocalizer' of
>   undefined

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bcvdd6

```
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import { momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      events: [{
          id: 0,
          title: 'All Day Event very long title',
          allDay: true,
          start: new Date(2015, 3, 0),
          end: new Date(2015, 3, 1),
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: new Date(2015, 3, 7),
          end: new Date(2015, 3, 10),
        },

        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'DTS STARTS',
          start: new Date(2016, 2, 13, 0, 0, 0),
          end: new Date(2016, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0),
        },

        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'DTS ENDS',
          start: new Date(2016, 10, 6, 0, 0, 0),
          end: new Date(2016, 10, 13, 0, 0, 0),
        },

        {
          id: 4,
          title: 'Some Event',
          start: new Date(2015, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0),
          end: new Date(2015, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0),
        }
      ]
    };  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BigCalendar
          localizer={localizer}
            events={this.state.events}
            startAccessor="start"
            endAccessor="end"
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import like this :

```js
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';

<Calendar
    localizer={localizer}
    events={this.state.events}
    startAccessor="start"
    endAccessor="end"
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

check the docs, i've fixed this with this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      events: [{
          id: 0,
          title: 'All Day Event very long title',
          allDay: true,
          start: new Date(2015, 3, 0),
          end: new Date(2015, 3, 1),
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: new Date(2015, 3, 7),
          end: new Date(2015, 3, 10),
        },

        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'DTS STARTS',
          start: new Date(2016, 2, 13, 0, 0, 0),
          end: new Date(2016, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0),
        },

        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'DTS ENDS',
          start: new Date(2016, 10, 6, 0, 0, 0),
          end: new Date(2016, 10, 13, 0, 0, 0),
        },

        {
          id: 4,
          title: 'Some Event',
          start: new Date(2015, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0),
          end: new Date(2015, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0),
        }
      ]
    };  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Calendar
          localizer={localizer}
            events={this.state.events}
            startAccessor="start"
            endAccessor="end"
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
BigCalendar.setLocalizer(BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment));
```